# Most Efficient Way to insert 300K rows from remote SQL Server into local Access table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ado, dao

I'm currently retrieving ~300K rows from a SQL Server (from within Access) using and ADODB.Connection/Recordset.
I'm then inserting those records into a table, currently via a DAO.Database/Recordset

Set up ADODB connection and assign results to 'results':

```
StrQuery = "Select * from tbl"
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
results = rst.GetRows
```

Insert into DAO recordset 'rs':

```
For row = 0 To UBound(results, 2)
    rs.AddNew
        For col = 0 To UBound(results, 1)
            If IsNumeric(results(col, row)) = True Then
                tmp = Round(results(col, row), 4)
            Else
                tmp = results(col, row)
            End If
            rs.Fields(col + 1) = results(col, row)
        Next col
    rs.Update
Next row
```

Is this the most efficient way to do it, or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Can you just create a linked table?  If so, then you could run a create table off of it to a new table, which I'd imagine would be a lot faster.

Comment: Was hoping I could do it with pure VBA, tried creating a linked table with vba, but get the old 'cannot find installable isam'.  I know it can be done, I've done it before, just don't have the precise code to hand.  I've created the linked table by hand.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need a copy of the data locally?  Because that's a pretty big drag on resources, and there's a reason that Access supports linked tables.  And if you need it locally, do you really need **all** of it?

Comment: That isn't all of it.  The servers aren't very fast so I need to retrieve data to local sources where it can be manipulated.

Comment: Under most circumstances DAO.Recordset inserts tend to be the fastest way.